# A problem about manipulated list with COMPILATION ERROR

Tags: c++, list

This is the question: //The question is solved
The test file consists of a single test case.
The first line contains a number N ( 1<= N <= 1000) indicating the initial
number of elements in the list. Then there will be N integers
representing the initial elements in the list. Next line will be an integer
Q( 1 <= Q <= 50) which means the number of operations. After that,
there will be Q lines of operations in the following format:
(1) 1 i val : insert "val" after the i-th element
(2) 2 i :delete element at i-th position
(3) 3 i j: reverse interval [i,j] of the list
(4) 4 i: output the i-th element in the list

Whereas my code as below has passed in my local compiler but failed when summit with the compilation error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    //Create variable states the number of member in the list
    int number;
cin >> number;

//Create the list "list"
list <int> list;

//Input the member value
for (int i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    int value;
    cin >> value;
    list.push_back(value); 
}

//Set the number of case
int caseNum;
cin >> caseNum;

//Set instruction
int instruction;
for (int i = 0; i < caseNum; i++) {
    cin >> instruction;
    if (instruction == 1) {
        int pos = 0; 
        int val = 0;
        cin >> pos >> val;
        std::list <int>::iterator it = list.begin();
        advance(it, pos);
        list.insert(it, val);
    }
    else if (instruction == 2) {
        int dpos = 0;
        cin >> dpos;
        std::list <int>::iterator it1 = list.begin();
        advance(it1, dpos-1);
        list.erase(it1);
    }
    else if (instruction == 3) {
        int rfirst = 0; 
        int rlast = 0;
        cin >> rfirst >> rlast;
        std::list <int>::iterator start = list.begin();
        std::list <int>::iterator end = list.begin();
        advance(start, rfirst-1);
        advance(end, rlast);
        reverse(start, end);
    }
    else if (instruction == 4) {
        int p;
        cin >> p;
        std::list <int>::iterator it4 = list.begin();
        advance(it4, p-1);
        cout << *it4 << endl;
    }
}
return 0;
```

}

Test Case (Sample input) as follow: 
6
1 2 3 4 5 6
12
1 3 10
2 1
4 4
3 3 5
4 3
2 2
1 2 7
3 1 4
4 2
2 5
3 2 5
4 4

Sample output:
4
5
7
5

Thank you so much!

Comment: "failed when summit with the compilation error" - what's the error? Also, turn on all compiler warnings with the `-Wall` flag. Maybe their system is compiling with `-Wall -Werror`, which treats any warning as an error

Comment: Yeah I think the system is set like that. But then I have the compilation error with the reverse statement. So do you know what can I do? Thxx

Comment: You enable `-Wall -Werror` _on your system_ and see if you get any errors. If you do, fix them and try to submit again

Comment: You should `#include <algorithm>` since you use `std::reverse` - and `<iterator>` since you use `std::advance` etc.

Answer (score -1):

```
list <int> list;
```

Naming a list "list" or any using class names as object names is very bad idea. 
Different compilers (and even versions of compilers) may interpret it in different way. Let's take as an example `list.push_back(value);`. List in this case can be understood as:

- a specific object of class list named "list" (then it's fine)
- a class itself (then it will fail to
  compile)

Comment: Good advice, but this is really not an attempt at answering the question, is it?

Comment: "Whereas my code as below has passed in my local compiler but failed when summit with the compilation error. "
If his local computer os is windows and his summit place is working on linux then it is solution. I used to have similiar problem caused by one of my variables called "time"

Comment: There's no ambiguity here. Had it been a global variable, it would have been.